# How to display errors in PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I've set in my php.ini file the values:

```
display_errors  On
display_startup_errors  On
```

And in my laravel application:

```
 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

But when i purpose write some gibberish in my controller method the page gets blank instead of displaying an error. What else is suppressing this to show an error message?

Comment: Did you try to add also `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Write this - ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); - in either your controller file where you get the blank or else you can write in main file like index.php. make sure if you use namespace in your class then write this below the namespace

Comment: I set the error_reporting(E_ALL); I think in phpinfo() it's showing: error_reporting 32767. Actually I wouldn't like to put those lines in the application. I've had it working on windows without a hassle.

Comment: Be sure that you edit correct __php.ini__..

Comment: There is so many, maybe the wrong one. But phpinfo gets updated.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings Was xdebug.force_display_errors=Off. It overrides the other settings obviously.

Comment: You might find this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36269588/2675981) useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was xdebug.force_display_errors=Off in php.ini. It overrides the other settings obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Got to the location /etc/php/7.0/apache2 and also enable the error on in php.ini residing here.Don't forget to restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

Add ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top of the code. 
Once you finish debugging, you can remove it. 
Also you can set these up based on environment variables.
For example you can set constant `DEVELOPMENT` to true only in development environment and use following code to enable error reporting

```
if (defined('DEVELOPMENT') && DEVELOPMENT === true)
{
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
}
```